# How to I programmatically find the Backcolor of a DateTimePicker Control

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

The backcolor of a default `DateTimePicker` control seems to be `Color.White`, but can this change based on a users theme colours and how do I find out what it is currently set to?

(There is no backcolour property and `DateTimePicker.DefaultBackColor` returns `SystemColors.Control` which is not actually correct)

I guess that if someone can confirm that this can't change then I am safe to hard code it?

EDIT:

The basis of this question was not actually a typo, it was the fact that `BackColor` does not show up in my `DateTimePicker` control intellisense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that there is no `BackColour` property. But there is a `BackColor` property. ;)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0625h0ta.aspx

However, `BackColor` might not be what you are looking for.

> Setting the BackColor has no effect on the appearance of the DateTimePicker. To set the background color for the drop-down calendar of the DateTimePicker, see the CalendarMonthBackground property.

Comment: Thanks - strangely BackColor does not show up in my intellisense. I don't actually want to set it just find the value so this works for me